# How to show/hide Profile based on Price set Total on a Contribution page?

Tags: ui, jquery

I would like to hide/show my "Custom Profile Group" based on the value of "Price Set Total". I already have an extension with this Jquery, but seems to be not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
  CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScript("
     CRM.$(function($) {
        hideshowMainProfile();
    $('#priceset [price]').bind('keyup',hideshowMainProfile);

    function hideshowMainProfile() {
        let priceValue = $('#priceset [price]').val();
    if (priceValue.length > 1) {
      $('.crm-public-form-item.crm-group.custom_pre_profile-group').show();
    }
    else {
      $('.crm-public-form-item.crm-group.custom_pre_profile-group').hide();
    }
  }
    });
");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use calculateTotalFee() to check if total amount is > 0.

```
CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScript("
  CRM.$(function($) {
    hideshowMainProfile();
    $('#priceset [price]').bind('change keyup click blur', hideshowMainProfile);

    function hideshowMainProfile() {
      if (calculateTotalFee() > 0) {
        $('.crm-public-form-item.crm-group.custom_pre_profile-group').show();
      }
      else {
        $('.crm-public-form-item.crm-group.custom_pre_profile-group').hide();
      }
    }
  });
");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks